# How to connect the modem to wall jack through a BIX1A panel?

Tags: ethernet, internet

I'm using WIFI in my apartment now but planning to use wire to connect to my desktop with the wall jack. No telephone or TV cable used here.

The modem is connected by fibre in a closet and there is a panel. I googled it and found the panel is a BIX1A panel. There are 3 wall jacks in the apartment， living room, den, and bedroom, and there are 3 wires connected to the panel. I don't know what are the 3 white cables and the taped blue wire used for.

I don't know how to connect the modem to the panel to make the wall jacks work. I'm thinking to connect the modem with the panel.

Should I connect the modem WAN output to the panel with a wire?

Where is the input on the panel?

I don’t know which room the three cables on the panel are connected to, but I want to use the jack in the living room. Does each wall jack need input on the panel? (Which means I need to figure out which one on the panel is connected to the living room wall jack?)

The color code seems to be T-568B. Jacks are Belden C 5E, so CAT5E Jacks. I just googled and learned, if anything unclear, my apologies.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The 3 white cables appear to be coaxial cables, that presumably go to the other port with the coaxial connector on your 3 rooms with jack plates as illustrated in your first picture.

The extra blue (presumably Cat5e) cable is a mystery if you only have 3 known wall jacks. It goes somewhere, but only the installer knows where, now.

If you only want the one port active, you should just sort out what wire that is (there are several ways that don't require buying specialized tools you'll use once, perhaps - such as a low voltage battery and a voltmeter if you happen to own one of those.)

Given that you want to run network, what I can find so far (I've never used this exact part) indicates that you probably just want to remove the BIX1A from the wall wires and terminate them (or the one you care about) on Cat5e jacks, which can be in surface mounts on the back of the cabinet. The specific part number you have is NOT Cat5e rated (the BIX1A**4** shown below is) and the special termination tool is absurdly expensive for one-time use (and not standard/interchangeable with other common network punchdown tools that have lower cost versions available, such as you'd use on a jack.) Some jacks include a free plastic "110 tool", and metal ones are not too expensive.

[image: BIX1A4 from cablek.com website - no affiliation or endorsement]

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you mean that I can just remove the wire that I want to use from the panel, and then give it a jack and input it on the black modem WAN output?

Comment: Remove from the panel, connect it to a jack (female) & use a patch cord (male-to-male) to connect to the modem. Don't just slap a plug (male) on it - you can do that, but it tends not to be reliable long-term - and the tool required for that (crimper & dies) costs more than a "punchdown tool" for jacks (but for your size of job, a jack with free plastic tool and using a wirecutter to remove the excess wire from the jack probably makes the most sense._

Answer (score 1):

belden part number AX100798 is a 6 port modular jack modulw that can fit into the BIX rack replacing, or beside the QCBIX1A

But as you seem have only 3 cables it's probably simpler to use regular "RJ45" jacks mounted in a surface box inside the cabinet.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully there is a diagram on the panel door that gives a bit more information.

The three white cables coiled and taped probably go to the three CATV outlets on your three jack panels(the left jack). You could verify that by simply removing the jack plated from the wall and examining the connections. The blue cable could be another means to connect the modem but not needed because you stated it's already connected by fiber optics.

The three CAT-5 cables probably go to the cat-5 jacks in each of your three rooms. They have already been punched into the strip in the panel so you'd need to determine which one goes to your desk and use a patch cord from your modem to the appropriate slot on the strip. There could be some writing or markings on the cables telling you which one is which. If not, time to experiment. hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no diagram. I plan to use a wire to connect the modem and punch the other side into panel 1, if the panel doesn't connect to the right place, then try panels 2 and 3.